# How do I write a MySQL LIKE clause using qmark syntax with the oursql Python library?

Tags: python, mysql, syntax-error

I'm using the oursql Python library to talk to a MySQL database.  I want to write code to search for users by name or email address.  This is the code I have currently:

```
query = get_query()
cursor.execute("""
    SELECT *
      FROM users
     WHERE full_name LIKE '%?%'
        OR email LIKE '%?%';""", (query, query))
```

This code throws an exception:

`ProgrammingError: 0 parameters expected, 2 given`

Apparently the parser thinks the question mark is apart of the single-quoted string, and therefore isn't doing the substitution.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `%`'s in the argument to `LIKE` are part of the data you want to pass to the DB-API module's `execute` method, so they need to be part of the argument you pass for the placeholder, not part of the SQL query itself. For example:

```
query = '%%%s%%' % (get_query(),)
cursor.execute("""
    SELECT *
      FROM users
     WHERE full_name LIKE ?
        OR email LIKE ?;""", (query, query))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work, too:

```
query = get_query()
cursor.execute("""
    SELECT *
      FROM users
     WHERE full_name LIKE '%' || ? || '%'
        OR email LIKE '%' || ? || '%';""", (query, query))
```